# Create a simple redirect rule to a Joomla site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

How i can create a new redirection rule to joomla's "Redirect Manager" or .htaccess file which can redirect guests from something like "something/item/13269248" to "somethingelse/item/13269248" BUT with any id there?

Comment: Is this for a menu item, link in an article, upon logging in? Please explain in a little more detail ;)

Comment: no there are no menu item links. It is a web-app which looking for a number items if they are exists on not. If it is, the web-app parsing its contents and exports valuable info from it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and you can do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^something/item/(.*) /somethingelse/item/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

htaccess

```
Redirect something/item/13269248 somethingelse/item/13269248
```

if you come across any issues  let me know

Comment: i want to create a redirect from something/item/(anynumber) to somethingelse/item/(anynumber) and of course anynumber must be the same on those 2

Comment: this isnt what i need! please help me

Comment: I'll try to work on it and figure it out for you. I'm not quite familiar with dynamic url redirects

Comment: yeah me too and i dont know how i can search for it. Thanks a lot for your time Dasun!